# UV Orientation Display

Tags: uv

Can anyone suggest a UV Editor addon which shades UVs according to whether they're flipped or not? One of the few basic features I miss from other 3D software. [image]

Comment: Hi :). The shipped UV Magic something addon can do that i believe ;)

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out. :)

Comment: Took a quick look at the Magic UV addon. It's definitely useable but relies on the user hitting the Update button regularly (to redraw the overlay) while editing uvs. I'm actually surprised the Blender devs didn't consider a red/blue UV display mode when they implemented the exact same thing for face normals. I know a while back there were multiple proposals on Right-Click Select,